# Using MathematicalProgram with no cost

Tags: python, drake

I would like to use Drake to find the critical points of a gradient. I obtained the gradient symbolically using the .Jacobian function. The thing is, I don't have a cost, I just want to find the roots. I have some constraints and my 2x1 continuous variable, but where do I go from here?

Comment: What constraint do you want to impose on your J and H?

Comment: nothing on H. I don't really use H. I want to find the critical points [t1,t2] of J, and said points should satisfy 0< t1, t2 < 2*pi, and t1 > t2+epsilon (i.e. t1 != t2).

Comment: By critical points, do you mean ∂J/∂t1 = 0 and ∂J/∂t2=0?

Comment: yes thats what i mean

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer. You just have to define a constraint that says J = 0. Drake figures it out as a constraint satisfaction problem and solves it.